# caught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module | Solution using babelrc or webpack config and not package json because of constraints

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

## **Using import statement works fine in dev environment but breaks in prod**

I am working on a monorepo consisting of lots of other repositories.

I have a lazy loader function like this in React:

```
const lazilyLoadLocale = async (locale: Locale): Promise<Locales> => {
  if (localeMap[locale]) return localeMap[locale] as Locales
  return import(`./${locale}.json`)
    .then((data) => {
      localeMap[locale] = { ...data }
      return data.default as Locales
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`Unable to load locale - ${locale}. Error: ${err.message}`)
      return english
    })
}
```

the function works as expected in dev, however since I am using import and when bundling with all other apps from which get built simultaneously all of them seem to follow module type as `commonjs`.

And when I try to run the built bundle, I get this error in console:

```
caught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module (at runtime.js:1:2637)
```

Please note that I can't add `type: 'module'` in package.json as I don't have access to it and its common for all the files. What I can tap into is `babelrc` and `webpack config`.

Comment: Did you get it resolved?